# Is the value discarded when converting to void pointer?

Tags: c++

Code:

```
class CFoo
{
   int a;
public:
   CFoo():a(1){}
   ~CFoo(){}
   getNum(){return a;}
};

void tfunc(void* data)
{
    CFoo* foo = static_cast<CFoo*>(data);
    std::cout << "Number: " << foo->getNum();
    delete foo;
}

int main()
{
   CFoo* foo = new CFoo;
   void* dt = static_cast<void*>(foo);
   tfunc(dt); // or tfunc(static_cast<void*>(food));

   return 0;
}
```

When converting to a void pointer, isn't the value going to be discarded, if yes, how can `foo->getNum()` be valid?

Comment: Nothing is discarded. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: Nothing is discard.  You simply tell the complier to point to the address where the `CFoo` is.

Comment: Well thanks guys, I guess that is the answer then. I got the idea from cplusplus, where the author said "Convert any type to void, evaluating and discarding the value." [What static_cast also can do](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/#static_cast)

Comment: @OfT The website says *Convert any type to void, evaluating and discarding the value.* that is *void*, not *void**.

Comment: Oh, my bad.. But I probably just starting thinking about void* because I can't really imagine any use-cases for converting into a void?

Comment: @DeiDei Furthermore, even that tutorial's wording has a potentially incorrect interpretation. Because `int a = 3; (void) a;` doesn't do anything to the value in `a`, of course; it just discards the copy of the value lifted from `a` during the evaluation.

Comment: If we cast a pointer to `void`, that will also not do anything to the object referenced by that pointer. A conversion doesn't harm the original value. If we convert `3` to floating-point using `(double) 3`, we have `3.0`, and we still have `3`.  A cast to `void` is just a kind of evaluation dead-end that is sometimes used. It expresses "we are evaluating this expression just for its side effect, and don't want its value at all". Or "we are ignoring the return value of this function on purpose, not by accident".

Comment: @Kaz, so that was what he meant. Thanks for making it that clear, it reallyx1000 helped.

Comment: It's also sometimes used to silence compiler warnings about unused function parameters. But I rarely see anyone actually type out a full `static_cast<void>(expression);`. I usually just see a plain C-style cast, i.e. `(void) expression;`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It makes sense, since there is only one way to cast to `(void)` and there are no safety issues since the discarded value cannot be used, and so cannot do any harm. E.g. there would never be a situation like, `"cast to void strips const qualifier, use const_cast!"`. :)

Comment: @Kaz: Yes, I agree. In fact, I was understating the case. It's not that I rarely see a `static_cast` to void. I have literally never seen it until I typed it in the comment above.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Haha! Watch this: `dynamic_cast<void>(obj)`. Is this really a `void`? What does RTTI say ...

Answer (score 0):

> When converting to a void pointer, isn't the value going to be discarded.

The value that is converted by your statement is the pointer, not the object to which the pointer points.

```
void* dt = static_cast<void*>(foo);
```

The value of the variable `foo` is the address of some `CFoo` object.  The statement defines a new variable, `dt`, with the same value (i.e., `foo` and `dt` both point to the same address), but the compiler won't let you dereference `*dt`---it will not allow you to fetch a `void` object from that address---because the `void` type has no values.

When your program calls `tfunc`, the formal argument `data` also gets a copy of the same value (i.e., it points to the same address), and finally so does the local variable `foo` inside `tfunc`.

The declared type of the local `foo` inside `tfunc` is pointer to `CFoo`, so the compiler will allow you to dereference that; And, it makes sense because you know that `foo` actually does point to a legitimate `CFoo` object.